# coffeescript inside php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, coffeescript

Is it possible to use coffeescript inside .php file, for example :

```
<!--test.php-->
<html>
   <head>
      <title> use coffeescript inside php file
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>how to use coffeescript</h1>
       <p><?php echo $lorem ?></p>

       <script type="text/javascript">
          // i want to use coffeescript here 
          (function() {
              alert ('hello world')
          });
       </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

If I want to use coffeescript in my php file what should I do to make it work?

Comment: No. CoffeeScript will not run in your browser. It has to be *compiled into Javascript* before being used. You should compile your CoffeeScript into a Javascript file and then link to it.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: Incorrect. You can include coffeescript compiler in one script tag, then use another `<script type="text/coffeescript">` with CoffeeScript (note the type though). See [here](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts). It is slower though, since compilation is occuring on clientside each time the page is loaded; preprocessing on serverside once and serving many times is definitely preferred.

Comment: @Amadan Well, sure, you can make it work, but it is taking developer convenience a little too far, imo.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: I agree with you, but "can't be done" and "it's not recommended for performance reasons" are two very different statements.

Comment: @Amadan You are right.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why not.

https://github.com/alxlit/coffeescript-php

Load your coffee in a var, compile it, and stick the resulting JS variable between the `<script>` tags.